# Insert newline into javascript string

Tags: javascript, insert, newline

I have read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857304/return-a-string-with-newlines-inserted), but I can't get it to work in my situation.

I'm building a list of names from a json array returned from a php script. After the below code I'm putting the goTosList string into a label via jquery. I need each name to be on a new line.

The below code is just outputting

```
var goTosList = '';
if (data !== 'empty') {
    // Build the go tos list as a comma-separated string
    $.each(data, function(index,element) {
        goTosList += (element['name'] === undefined ? '' : element['name']) + '\n\r';
    });
}
```

I've tried just `\r` and just `\n` and without the single quotes. I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are output is HTML and you want newlines you have two options:

Either use a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag as a wrapper to your text (not suitable here I think)

```
<pre>some Text

with newlines</pre>
```

or add [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) instead of `\n\r`:

```
some Text<br>with newlines
```

So in your code this would translate to

```
goTosList += (element['name'] === undefined ? '' : element['name']) + '<br>';
```

and later on insert this into the DOM by

```
$('#yourLabel').html( goTosList );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that didn't work. Adding `<br>` as you suggest just adds the tag as text. It's rendered in the label as "John Smith<br>Mary Johnson".

Comment: @eventide Which command do you use to insert the text in the page?

Comment: As soon as I read your question I realized that was the problem. I was using `$('#label').text(goTosList);` Changing `.text` to `.html` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I also want to add line number, Is it possible?

Comment: @VSH Not sure, what you are up to. At the point where you create the string to be inserted, you can obviously also add line numbers, but I don't see the connection to this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845228/how-to-put-line-number-in-source-code-after-parse-in-html-page