# How to put line number in source code after parse in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular js and mongoDB, In mongoDB I have some text with \n, So each  line comes into the new line based on \n, But I am also want to add line number for each line.

**HTML CODE**

```
{{sorceText}}
```

**Controller code**

```
 $scope.sorceText=" ANB+IO:UI+OPO++7866:1111222'\OKP+JJJJ+PP++IOOIO:9989+KKKKKK+II+22:33'
 IIOI+IOIOOI+OOOO:13:1:IA+AA346+4'
 MSG+8'
 LLL+PLPL:MLML+52519950'
 NBK+290818:0000+MJL+LKL+OK+91'
 KWNN+250'
 NFR'
 KK+KK:MMM'"
```

**Displaying Now:**

```
     ANB+IO:UI+OPO++7866:1111222'\OKP+JJJJ+PP++IOOIO:9989+KKKKKK+II+22:33'
     IIOI+IOIOOI+OOOO:13:1:IA+AA346+4'
     MSG+8'
     LLL+PLPL:MLML+52519950'
     NBK+290818:0000+MJL+LKL+OK+91'
     KWNN+250'
     NFR'
     KK+KK:MMM'
```

**Expected** I want to be add line number of each line.

1. ANB+IO:UI+OPO++7866:1111222'\OKP+JJJJ+PP++IOOIO:9989+KKKKKK+II+22:33'
2. IIOI+IOIOOI+OOOO:13:1:IA+AA346+4'
3. MSG+8'
4. LLL+PLPL:MLML+52519950'
5. NBK+290818:0000+MJL+LKL+OK+91'
6. KWNN+250'
7. NFR'
8. KK+KK:MMM'

Comment: What is `{{sourceText}}` wrapped in?  A `pre` tag or something else? Basically you will need to split the string into the an array on the new line character. Then bind that to an appropriately styled list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be helpful to you

```js
 var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.controller("myctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.sorceText="ANB+IO:UI+OPO++7866:1111222'\OKP+JJJJ+PP++IOOIO:9989+KKKKKK+II+22:33'\nIIOI+IOIOOI+OOOO:13:1:IA+AA346+4'\nMSG+8'\nLLL+PLPL:MLML+52519950'\nNBK+290818:0000+MJL+LKL+OK+91'\nKWNN+250'\nNFR'\nKK+KK:MMM'"
 
 $scope.sorceText_arr=[];
 var arr=$scope.sorceText.split("\n");
 $scope.sorceText_arr=arr;
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
         <div ng-repeat="i in sorceText_arr">
         <div>{{$index+1}} - {{i}}</div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not getting \n, Because \n converting into new in controller itself when I am fetching from DB

Comment: so how do you know its going to be a next line, because its single line

Comment: When I am printing after call, It showing me in next line

Comment: You can check me new question for reference

Comment: can we put these line into the array

Comment: Above code is working fine, It will work with space?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ol`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp)

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ppaazg?file=home/home.html)

In js split to array this string.

```
$scope.items=$scope.sorceText.split('\n');
```

In html use loop on this array:

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But it is not working for me, I am not getting \n in the controller, \n converting into next line itself